# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while posting in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'https://your_url.aspx', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : school, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
```

This is my code to post some form data to a specific url, but I am getting the following error:

```
POST https://your_url.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ magic.js:20
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
https://your_url.aspx. No 'Access-Control-
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is 
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I looked around for how to allow access-control-allow-origin and used in $.ajax

```
beforeSend: function(request){
  request.setHeaderRequest("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
}
```

also later on after seeing more responses in stackoverflow I changed setHeaderRequest to addHeaderReuest, but even then I did not get to see the response from the server, although the errors were removed. The console appeared blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error came because you are trying to hit another domain from your domain. Using the **Same Origin Policy**, we can request only those url's which exists in the same domain. The **cross domain request** generally known as **CORS** is not allowed by browser until we have an authentication from another site. The **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** response header indicates whether the response can be shared with resources with the given origin. check the documention [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: writing crossDomain: true didn't help either.

Comment: no, Here you are cleraly getting the error message as `Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: the another website which you want to hit may don't allow the cross domain request

Comment: OK, so changes have to be made on the server side?

Comment: yes, there you have to write code to allow the cross domain requests